# How do I set one form value as another form value using reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I have a form that takes input from the user. The form has a switch that is toggled true and false that will set value the same if true and if false they won't be. I then push to an array. It is a regular form the id of the form corresponds with the state names and uses is all input type.

```
constructor() {
    this.state({
       input1: '',
       input2: '',
       copyinput1: '',
       copyinput2: '',
       infoSame: false,
       array: []
     })
}

handleFormInput(event) {
    const target = event.target;
    const value = target.type === 'input' ? target.value : target.value
    const id = target.id;
    this.setState({
      [id]:value
    })
}

handleFormSubmit() {
    if(infoSame === false) {
        array.push({
            input1: this.state.input1,
            input2: this.state.input2,
            copyinput1: this.state.copyinput1,
            copyinput2:  this.state.copyinput2
        })
    }
    else {
        //here is where I want input1 and input2 to be the values
        //for copyinput1 and copyinput2
        //How can this be achieved?
    }
    this.setState({
       input1: '',
       input2: '',
       copyinput1: '',
       copyinput2: '',
       infoSame: false, 
    })
}
```

Comment: if `infoSame == true`, you want to have values like `copyinput1 = input1` and `copyinput2 = input2`?

Comment: yes I do @SkrewEverything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you just assign it?

Like:

```
handleFormSubmit() {
    if(infoSame === false) {
        array.push({
            input1: this.state.input1,
            input2: this.state.input2,
            copyinput1: this.state.copyinput1,
            copyinput2:  this.state.copyinput2
        })
    }
    else {
        //here is where I want input1 and input2 to be the values
        //for copyinput1 and copyinput2
        //How can this be achieved?
        array.push({
            input1: this.state.input1,
            input2: this.state.input2,
            copyinput1: this.state.input1,
            copyinput2:  this.state.input2
        })
    }
    this.setState({
       input1: '',
       input2: '',
       copyinput1: '',
       copyinput2: '',
       infoSame: false, 
    })
}
```